# Converting non-UTF-8 text into displayable HTML - What are those Asian characters?

Tags: php, html, regex, encoding, utf-8

We need to be able to take content from an HTML file with UNKNOWN character encoding, modify the contents, and then display it in the user's browser. Any test file that I create works perfectly, but some of the files we've taken from a customer do not. Those files will not be modified since the code searches the content using regex, and they will display odd characters in the browser, usually a jumble of Asian characters that I don't recognize at the bottom of the page.

I've tried utf8_encode, htmlspecialchars, iconv, and even a third-party API that I'd hoped might handle this. Nothing so far has worked.

If I open one of these problem HTML files in Sublime, everything looks perfect. If I view it using vim, I see `<feff><feff>` before the . If I ever try to use one of those aforementioned PHP functions to correct this file, I get 6 unrecognized characters at the start of the file where those 2 s are, and 1 unrecognized character before every less-than sign. (Greater-thans aren't affected.)

If I copy/paste the contents of one of these files from Sublime directly into my code, the regex works fine and the HTML displays perfectly.

If I simplify my regex to ignore less-than signs (some of them search for HTML tags), they still will not detect any matches, even though the parts that should match contain no unrecognized characters.

That's a lot I know, but it's had my head spinning for a couple of days now. Any insight would be nothing short of heroic.

Comment: `<feff>` that's the UTF-16 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) being displayed in Vim - it's a non-visible information character being represented as `<feff>`; that's not the literal value which is why your regex doesn't match.

Comment: My regex is actually looking for <a> tags with an href, and <img> tags with a src. The <feff> is not in any of those tags, only at the beginning. Could it sill be causing my regex to fail?

Comment: Yes - the file itself is encoded in UTF-16, which [isn't supported](http://wisercoder.com/php-preg_match-failing-reason-blame-utf-16/) in `preg_*` functions, so you'll need to convert the file to utf-8 first; you might want to look at [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: One of my coworkers recommended this too. It SHOULD work, but md_detect_encoding is unfortunately returning false. One road block after another.

Answer (score 0):

Our best solution to this problem has been to use DOMDocument's loadHTMLFile() method.